# Non www to https://www

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I am running NodeJs application in ubuntu 16.04 and I want requests: `http://` and `http://www` to redirect to `https://www`.

I tried achieving this by editing  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.net
    ServerName www.example.net
    ServerAlias example.net www.example.net

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-access_log

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.net$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteRule (.+) http://www.example.net$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Note: where it is example.net, I am writing my domain.

Answer (score 0):

**In the VirtualHost for port 80**

Couple points:

1) The second `RewriteCond` is not required, `%{HTTP_HOST}` will always be set to something if you get to the VirtualHost.

2) `ServerAlias example.net www.example.net`.  Remove the www.example.net, it is already set in `ServerName`.

3) to help debug Apache, you can put `LogLevel debug` and try it again.

4) Your `RewriteRule (.+) http://www.example.net$1 [R=301,L]` should actually be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your rule:

1. redirects to http.
2. `(.+)`: means some character, 1 to n times.  Of you have nothing (like `http://www.example.com`, your rule never matches.

The new rule will ensure anything, present or not, after the requested domain will be added to the https redirection.

**In the VirtualHost for port 443**

In port 443, the traffic is already https, so only the addition of "www" is required:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will only add the "www" when the requested domain is `https://example.net`.

Comment: I have done everything what you said and the good thing is that it redirects all requests to https://www, but now I'm facing "redirected you too many times." when I'm trying to open the web.

Comment: This rewrite rule goes in the VirtualHost for port 80.  In the one for port 443, do not  put the exact same redirect.  See my edit in the answer.